# self join with inner join on other tables together

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, self-join

I have a database with 3 tables records, categories, relational.

```
records (id, lat, lng)
categories (c_id, c_value)
relational (r_id, c_id)

records
id  | lat      | lng
----------------------
1    23.57258   -35.28412
2    23.54855   -35.18881
3    23.74128   -35.17469

categories
c_id | c_value
---------------
100    groceries
101    bags
102    drinks

relational
id  |  c_id
------------
1     100
1     102
2     101
3     100
```

The relational.r_id = records.id and the relational.c_id = categories.c_id
I want to take pairs from records with different c_value, so I want to make a self join in records and inner join in categories and relational.
I've made this without the self join in records

```
SELECT id, lat, lng, c_value 
FROM records 
JOIN relational 
  ON records.id = relational.id 
JOIN categories 
  ON relational.c_id = categories.c_id 
WHERE c_value = "V1"
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work. I have problem with the R1.c_value.

```
SELECT R1._id, R1.lat, R1.lng, R1.c_value, R2._id, R2.lat, R2.lng, 
       R2.c_value 
FROM records R1, records R2 
JOIN relational 
  ON records.id = relational.id 
JOIN categories 
  ON relational.c_id = categories.c_id 
WHERE R1.c_value = "groceries" AND R2.c_value = "bags"
```

Do you know how can I combine those 3 joins in order to take 2 rows from records with the criteria of the other tables?
I want to have an output like this:
For "groceries" and "bags" as c.value

```
1 | 23.57258  |  -35.28412  |  groceries | 2  | 23.54855  |  -35.18881  |  bags
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mix "comma join" and "join" syntax in the same query....it's generally a bad idea to USE "comma join" notation at all.

Comment: I find this question quite difficult to understand. Can you please include some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found exactly what I wanted. My query should be like this. Thanks for the help and the idea anyway.

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.lat, r1.lng, c1.c_value, r2.id, r2.lat, r2.lng, c2.c_value
FROM records r1 JOIN relational rl1 ON rl1.id = r1.id
JOIN categories c1 ON rl1.c_id = c1.c_id
JOIN records r2 JOIN relational rl2 ON rl2.id = r2.id
JOIN categories c2 ON rl2.c_id = c2.c_id
WHERE  c1.c_value = "groceries" AND c2.c_value = "bags"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can self join `records` table along with `categories` and `relational` like this:

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.lat, r1.lng, r2.id, r2.lat, r2.lng, c.c_value
FROM records r1 JOIN relational rl ON r1.id = rl.r_id
JOIN records r2 ON r2.id = rl.r_id
JOIN categories c ON rl.c_id = c.c_id
WHERE r1.id <> r2.id;
```

Comment: This looks good for 1 c_value. Can you help me with the query if I want the c_value to be different in r1 and different in r2?

Comment: In that case, you will have to join it twice on `categories` table and provide different values.

Comment: Do you mean to put c1.c_value, c2.c_value in select and then join categories c1 on rl.c_id= c1.c_id   join categories c2 on rl.c_id= c2.c_id where c1.c_value = "V1" AND c2.c_value = "V2". I tried this but it returns empty result. :/

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain me more how to do it? Because I can't figure it out.

Comment: We have `c.c_value = 'V1';` in the query so it can't be different. Could you add expected output in the question?

Comment: @arek updated the answer and removed the condition, try now

Comment: But I want the condition with 2 c_value because I want to search every time something different. I want to find from the table records all the rows that have c_value = "groceries" and all of them that have c_value = "bags". And I need them to the same query with joins